# Data Designer - Link Data Extension to Contact Model via "Domain" link

Tags: marketing-cloud, contact

I have a data extension, which contains useful attributes at a domain level (e.g. # of products owned on a given domain, account level, etc) and I'm trying to link this into the data model via data designer.

Is there an easy way to link my new DE to the contact model? I don't see any standard "domain" field on the existing contact model and I was hoping to avoid creating an email address -> domain mapping data extension.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Cardinal relationships in Contact Builder are based on matching Attribute values; you can't use a substring.

The only solution would to create a Query Activity that extracts the domain part of an email address to a separate field, then you can include that Data Extension in your Contact Model.

Comment: I was concerned that would be the case - that's not really practical in this situation, as we're inserting data into ExactTarget in real-time, and then need to do a decision fork immediately inside a journey based on a value related to their domain (e.g. if someone trials a product ,and they belong to a company who has a certain "account status", then do x in the journey, otherwise do y").

Comment: Hi @JeffSinclair, I can think of a couple of solutions to achieve what you need in Journey Builder (and no, it doesn't involve a custom activity). What does the decision need to look like? How many branches are coming off it? Is it just a boolean test? Also, what are the subsequent activities? (email, sms, update contact data, etc).